# How to prevent timeline position moving when I click stop?

Tags: timeline

In the timeline I push `alt-a` to play and again to stop.

But the timeline position jumps ahead when I stop! So I keep having to drag it back to play again from the same place.

How do I make it stop moving around every time I play, so it is fixed, like in a DAW like Reaper or FL Studio?

Comment: left and right arrows to go one frame forwards or backwards, shift left and right arrows to go to beginning or to the end, top or down arrows to go to next or previous keyframe, shift top or down arrows to go 10 frames forwards or backwards, unfortunately I don't think there's any way to go to next or previous marker... but you can create a selection with P, alt P to get out. I don't know what you mean when you say that the timeline jumps ahead when you stop, it should stop where it is...

Comment: No, I don't want it to stop where it is. I want it to return to its last place. Most music apps I've worked with allow you stop or pause (one returns you to where you were working, and one keeps the position where you paused). Blender seems to have only the pause option.

Comment: yes I don't think there's a way to do it, it could have been a kind of marker but it doesn't exist and even the markers can't do it currently, what you can do is change the starting frame with S (and end frame with E) - perhaps the most similar to what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit:

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop the animation on the frame you started from.

## Old:

As @moonboots suggests, you can easly set the starting point by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> before playing the animation.

[image]

**You can use an alternative frame range.**

You can switch between the main frame range and the temporary one by pressing the *clock icon*.

[image]

Once you set the starting point, you can jump to the first frame (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>) without pausing the animation.

Comment: I'd like to be able to just keep pushing `alt-a` to replay, but until Blender adds a stop button this is as good as I'm going to get. Marking as answer, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my answer, adding the feature you are looking for.

Comment: cool I didn't know the escape function, not the most convenient though, but it can be changed in the preferences